# How to get text of hyperlink of webview once click in android?

Tags: java, android, webview, hyperlink

I am building an android application where a URL is loaded on a webView. Now in that URL, there are some Hyperlink's which is loaded when a user clicks on them. While click I get that URL string and a load that URL in webView.

Now I need when a user clicks on that Hyperlink I need to get that text of that Hyperlink. I had to google a lot yet did not get any good answers.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This function will show all resources text(hyperlink, image, css file, js file)

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            Log.d(TAG, "onLoadResource: " + url);
        }
    });
```

So you have to check before using it

```
if (!url.endsWith(".css") 
    && !url.endsWith(".js")
    && !url.endsWith(".otherformat") ) {
    // Show your url
}
```

Comment: I am loading an URL as a mention in above question, not an HTML file. How I can using a javascript function on it

Comment: When url is loaded, is that a html?

Comment: suppose this is a link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129050/how-to-get-text-of-hyperlink-of-webview-once-click-in-android" and this is loaded in webview.

Comment: any idea do you have?

Comment: It will give me URL and I need the text of the hyperlink. I don't think so it will work.

Comment: Do you know JavaScript? that can help me ?